# VS 2017 MVC error Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I was trying to add identity to my project and got this error

Server Error in '/' Application.

> Configuration Error Description: An error occurred during the
> processing of a configuration file required to service this request.
> Please review the specific error details below and modify your
> configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as
> allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This
> error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an
> application in IIS.

Source Error:

```
Line 41:   <system.web>
Line 42:       
Line 43:     <authentication mode="Forms">
Line 44:       <forms name="mycms" loginUrl="/Account/login"
Line 45:           protection="All" path="/" timeout="43200" />
```

and this is my web config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="YoubaanCoaching" />
        
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>



  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false"/>
    <add key="owin:AppStartup" value="false"></add>
  </appSettings>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.web>
      
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="mycms" loginUrl="/Account/login"
          protection="All" path="/" timeout="43200" />
    </authentication>
    <compilation>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there has to be slash(/) at the end of URL.
Try this

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="mycms" loginUrl="/Account/login/"
          protection="All" path="/" timeout="43200" />
    </authentication>
```